# Why can't I copy the terminating null this way?

Tags: c, null

I wanted to copy string with the following code and it didn't copy the '\0'.

```
void copyString(char *to, char *from)
{
    do{
        *to++ = *from++;
    }while(*from);
}
int main(void)
{
    char to[50];
    char from[] = "text2copy";
    copyString(to, from);
    printf("%s", to);
}
```

This is output to the code:

```
text2copyÇ■   ║kvu¡lvu
```

And every time I rerun the code the code, the character after text2copy changes, so **while(*from)** works fine but something random is copied instead of '\0'.

```
text2copyÖ■   ║kvu¡lvu
text2copy╨■   ║kvu¡lvu
text2copy╡■   ║kvu¡lvu
//etc
```

Why is this happenning?

Comment: Your copy code isn't safe if passed an empty string `""` because it looks beyond the end of the source (from) string.  For non-empty strings, your code doesn't copy the null byte, so the output (to) string is not properly null terminated.  There is no null pointer in your code, so it isn't clear how the title of your question meshes with the content.  The classic idiom for safe-ish string copying is some variant on `while ((*to++ = *from++) != '\0') ;` which copies the null byte and doesn't poke beyond the end of an empty string.  You could use `char to[50] = "XXXX…XXXX";` for better clarity.

Comment: Imagine that you are at the point in the loop where `*from` is the last character (the y in text2copy)  Then you copy that character from `*from` into `*to` and increment both.  Now `*from` is pointing to the '\0' and you do the test to see if you should exit the loop.  The test succeeds and the loop ends before '\0' is copied.  You can't actually fix that without checking the value of `*from` before incrementing it.  Something like: `int test; do { test = (*to++ = *from++); } while(test);` But that won't fix the problems pointed out by @JonathanLeffler

Comment: I am sure you already know this, and are doing this for learning purposes or what ever. But just in  case you are new to C and somehow missed it.  C stdlib already contains a function for string copy http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/

Comment: Thanks for your help JonathanLeffler and JerryJeremiah. I understood what goes wrong: loop ends before the null is copied. So, I solved the problem by checking the previous char. This worked for empty and full strings: do{*to++ = *from++;}while(*(from-1)); Do you think this code is safe @JonathanLeffler ?

Comment: @SuheylAkinli: You ask if `do { *to++ = *from++; } while (*(from-1));` is safe.  I believe the answer is yes, but it might be better to use: `do { *to++ = *from; } while (*from++ != '\0');` (where many people use just `while (*from++)` but I prefer the explicit comparison).  However, the difference is mostly trivial — and the top-testing `while` loop I showed previously is still the (more nearly) idiomatic C code.  There are some occasions when `do { … } while (…);` is correct, but you'll probably write 10 `while (…) { … }` for every `do { … } while (…)` loop — or the skew may be bigger.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you never copy the `'\0'` character at the end of the string.  To see why consider this:

The string passed in is a constant string sized exactly to fit the data:

```
char from[] = "text2copy";
```

It looks like this in memory:

```
            ----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----
   other memory |  t |  e |  x |  t |  2 |  c |  o |  p |  y | \0 | other memory
            ----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----
                   ^
                 from
```

Now let's imagine that you have done the loop several times already and you are at the top of the loop and `from` is pointing to the `'y'` character in text2copy:

```
            ----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----
   other memory |  t |  e |  x |  t |  2 |  c |  o |  p |  y | \0 | other memory
            ----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----
                                                           ^
                                                         from
```

The computer executes `*to++ = *from++;` which copies the `'y'` character to `to` and then increments both `to` and `from`.  Now the memory looks like this:

```
            ----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----
   other memory |  t |  e |  x |  t |  2 |  c |  o |  p |  y | \0 | other memory
            ----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----
                                                                ^
                                                              from
```

The computer executes `} while(*from);` and realizes that `*from` is false because it points to the `'\0'` character at the end of the string so the loop ends and the `'\0'` character is never copied.

Now you might think this would fix it:

```
void copyString(char *to, char *from)
{
    do{
        *to++ = *from++;
    } while(*from);
    *to = *from; // copy the \0 character
}
```

And it does copy the `'\0'` character but there are still problems.  The code even more fundamentally flawed because, as @JonathanLeffler said in the comments, for the empty string you peek at the contents of memory that is after the end of the string and because it was not allocated to you accessing it causes undefined behaviour:

```
            ----+----+----
   other memory | \0 | other memory
            ----+----+----
                   ^
                 from
```

The computer executes `*to++ = *from++;` which copies the `'\0'` character to `to` and then increments both `to` and `from` which makes from point to memory you don't own:

```
            ----+----+----
   other memory | \0 | other memory
            ----+----+----
                        ^
                      from
```

Now the computer executes `}while(*from);` and accesses memory that isn't yours.  You can point `from` anywhere with no problem, but dereferencing `from` when it points to memory that isn't yours is undefined behaviour.

The example I made in the comments suggests saving the value copied into a temporary variable:

```
void copyString(char *to, char *from)
{
    int test;
    do{
        test = (*to++ = *from++); // save the value copied
    } while(test);
}
```

The reason I suggested that particular way was to show you that the problem was WHAT you were testing and not about testing the loop condition afterwards.  If you save the value copied and then test that saved value later the character gets copied before it is tested (so the \0 gets copied) and you don't read from the incremented pointer (so there is no undefined behaviour)

But the example @JonathanLeffler had in his comments is shorter, easier to understand, and more idiomatic.  It exact does the same thing without declaring a named temporary variable:

```
void copyString(char *to, char *from)
{
    while ((*to++ = *from++) != '\0')
       ;
}
```

The code first copies the character and then tests the value that was copied (so the `'\0'` will be copied) but the incremented pointer is never dereferenced (so there is no undefined behaviour).

Comment: Such an exquisite answer.  Some day maybe the OP will accept your answer.  We can hope.

Comment: @gregspears I really like explaining that way with little pictures of the memory locations.  It seems so much more obvious when you do that.

Answer (score 0):

the posted code stops looping when it encounters the NUL byte, rather than afterwards.

Regarding:

```
}while(*from);
```

Suggest following that line with:

```
*to = '\0';
```